# Left Join in Hive is not returning expected results

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have 3 tables, one is datetable which contains only date, other 2 has data as follows.

datetable:

[image]

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

I am doing left join with date table as follows:

```
select * from 
(select distinct t.d,
coalesce(tab1.name,tab2.name,"") as name,
coalesce(tab1.id,tab2.id,"") as id,
coalesce(tab1.tgt_cnt,0) as tgt_cnt,
coalesce(tab2.a_cnt,0) as a_cnt,
coalesce(tab2.b_cnt,0) as b_cnt,
coalesce(tab2.c_cnt,0) as v_cnt
from datetable t
LEFT JOIN (select * from table1) tab1 on t.d = tab1.dt
LEFT JOIN (select * from table2) tab2 on t.d = tab2.dt) a
where (tgt_cnt <> 0 or a_cnt <> 0 or b_cnt <> 0 or c_cnt <> 0);
```

And I am getting following results.

[image]

My question is what happened to the record TOM. I am not sure why CG and Bob repeating twice. Is something wrong in my query.

Could you please suggest why TOM record not coming in the Left Join and why CG and BOB are repeating.

I am expecting following results.
[image]

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks,Babu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coalesce(tab1.name,tab2.name,"") as name` will replace the names in table2 with those in table1, so TOM never appeared because it got replaced by CG or BOB.

I'm guessing what you're trying to achieve here... seems like you want to combine table1 and table2. I think a full join is appropriate.

```
select * from (
select distinct
    coalesce(t1.dt, t2.dt) as dt,
    coalesce(t1.desc, t2.desc) as desc, 
    coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name, 
    coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
    coalesce(t1.tgt_cnt, 0) as tgt_cnt,
    coalesce(t2.a_cnt, 0) as a_cnt,
    coalesce(t2.b_cnt, 0) as b_cnt,
    coalesce(t2.c_cnt, 0) as c_cnt
from table1 t1
full join table2 t2
on t1.name = t2.name and t1.dt = t2.dt
) a
where (tgt_cnt <> 0 or a_cnt <> 0 or b_cnt <> 0 or c_cnt <> 0);
```

which will give

```
dt              desc    name    id      tgt_cnt a_cnt   b_cnt   c_cnt
6/29/2020       NULL    Tom     3       0       0       0       1
6/29/2020       AA      CG      1       3       1       1       0
6/29/2020       AA      Bob     2       3       0       0       0
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right. coalesce is overwriting tab2 name with tab1 name. We are getting same results with FULL JOIN  as well. how do I combine both tables data into single table without missing any data.

Comment: @Babu that's what my answer is doing. I did not miss any data. Please could you read my answer carefully again?

Comment: I tried FULL JOIN on dt field as I need to combine both tables based on dt. if dt is same, i need to combine both talbes. if it has same name, just take name from one table. if it is different name, one name should come in one row and another name in next row along with matching data

Comment: @Babu I've updated my answer to match dt as well. the results are still identical to your expected results.

Comment: got it. its working perfect. Thank you for your quick response. Greatly appreciated your help.